# Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jvm, daemon

I updated my IDE to Android Studio Arctic Fox version and was facing this issue when I tried to sync gradle after the upgrade was complete:

"`Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`"

[image]

I checked my java version, which was Java 17. I deleted my .gradle directory which didn't help. Reversed the gradle.properties changes made by the update. It didn't work either. I looked for maxPermSize value in my vm.studiooptions file. It wasn't there as suggested in some stackoverflow already asked questions.

Sharing the fix for this below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a few hours of looking up for solutions for this online and trying different things.

**This worked for me:**

File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Last line "JDK location was moved to **Gradle settings**. I clicked on this -> Gradle JDK -> Embedded JDK

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me on a mac, Im getting this error in cmd when trying to run an existing react native project.

Comment: what worked for me was the java-sdk version, which I changed and everything works fine, for newer versions of java this is not supported, 

openjdk version "1.8.0_345"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_345-bre_2022_08_04_23_35-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.345-b00, mixed mode)

Answer (score 14):

In JDK 17 `-XX:MaxPermSize=size` java option has been removed, use `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` instead.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#removed-java-options

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In your Android studio go to File--> settings-->(Build, Execution, Deployment)--->Build Tools---> Gradle.
Inside Gradle settings choose Embedded JDK.

[Here's a screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IUR5.png)

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this for me was changing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable on my computer from a JDK 17 version to a JDK 11 version.

I was running some commands that were using my computer's Java environment which was JDK 17 and my project did not support JDK 17.